# (Simple?) Label Placement for Line Graphs

Tags: optimization, graphics, charts, gis

I'm drawing elevation profiles showing the elevation gain/loss along a trail, similar to the one below:

[Sample Elevation Profile with hand-placed labels http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4079/profilewithgoodlabels.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4079/profilewithgoodlabels.png)

This is basically a line graph with distance from the start on the x-axis and elevation on the y-axis.

I'd like to provide fancy labels with spot elevations at interesting points along the trail, like the ones I have added by hand to the sample image. I'm looking for ideas on how best to place these labels so that:

- They don't overlap with each other
- They don't overlap with the profile itself, or at least this happens in a clean-looking way (seems it might be necessary in the middle of a steep valley, for example)
- They don't extend outside the box that limits the overall image

To achieve these objectives, I figure I can (at least):

- Flip the text around (see example)
- Choose appropriate lengths for leaders
- Choose appropriate angles for leaders (but minimizing the variation might be desirable for aesthetic reasons)
- Drop spot elevations for less-important places in crowded areas
- Abbreviate names in crowded areas (`PlaceName`s in my environment already support abbreviation in a really nice way, so switching from "South Twin Mountain" to "S Twin Mtn" is easy)
- Drop less-important annotations entirely in crowded areas

But I don't know how best to structure this algorithm. It seems like an optimization problem maybe? (Minimize the stinkiness associated with the annotation, and provide a numerical penalty for each of the things I'm trying to avoid?) But since there are a lot of discrete variables to optimize and I don't really care about the "best" solution (just a good, and preferably stable, one) I'm not sure what to do.

How are problems like this in graphics usually approached? Dynamic programming? Branch and bound? Is the optimization idea off base? Are there any useful libraries for .NET that I might want to look at?

(I don't want to cede this to a general graph-drawing library outright, because it is a key feature of the overall product and I have some more custom features planned that might be tough to jam into a general purpose graph-drawing library)

Comment: How's that going? Did you find the best algorithm?

Comment: I ended up going with the simulated annealing approach (after leaving this project aside for a while). It was fairly simple to implement, works rather well, and parts of it can be re-used for other things like labeling maps and selecting page layouts, even predicting which routes through the trail network might be good ones to hike.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

1. Mark the points where you want to put labels
2. Split them into groups with the distance of at least `2*size` between them
3. For each group, go from the right an try to put a label.
4. Try to put label to the right or to the left. See which results in lower length of the vertical line
5. If doesn't matter, try to put to the right
6. Unless it's the end of the group, then try to put it to the left

Now go again over the labels and see if any can be flipped from one side to another while shortening the length of vertical lines.

Should result in a decent output, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably place one label, then place the next, check if it overlaps the first, and if so flip it, if that doesn't work, nudge it upwards until it doesn't overlap anymore... as a starting point anyway. Maybe add a cost function as a distance from the ideal or default placement (if there were no other labels to get in the way), which is to be minimized. Then find the lowest-cost arrangement of labels. Can give flipping, and movement, and rotation, abbreviation, and dropping each a different cost.

Comment: That's a good idea, but what happens if the first choice isn't good and messes up the next several? For example, what if the first choice from left to right is to place a right-going label that covers up most of a valley and makes it impossible to place labels with long leaders coming up out of the valley for points that are down in the valley?

Comment: Well, then your overall cost would be higher because each subsequent label would have to be moved a greater distance. So I guess you *could* try every possible ordering of labels and then take the lowest cost one... this of course is highly inefficient, but perhaps you can come up with some heuristics to minimize the number of possibilties that need to be examined.

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me of a graphics project I did not too long ago.  It was to draw a mathematical graph (as in nodes and edges) in the most pleasing way possible.  There are several approaches but my favorite by far was the physics approach.  You treat each node as a charged particle that repels all others and each edge as a classical spring with some ideal length.  You run a few hundred time steps and eventually get to a stable state with an appropriate damping effect.

I see many parallels with your problem.  The text boxes are the nodes and the leader lines are the edges.

It will have to be modified.  For example there should be a positive force upward so they don't go below the graph.  You'd also have to incorporate the idea of flipping the text to the left or right.  But it should give a reasonable result on most inputs.

The article I referenced for my project was [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms).

Comment: Another good plan, I had heard of this approach before but it never crossed my mind thinking about this project. Thanks!